# How to pull files from a directory for an image gallery?

Tags: html, css

I've recently started learning html and for my first project i'm trying to create an image gallery that takes every png file from a directory and frames them on one page.

I've managed to make a very simple gallery that displays the images in a grid pattern but i haven't been able to make it take images straight from a folder without doing it manually.

I'm probably getting ahead of myself with such a project but any help is welcomed.

Current code is on github here:

http://ronsoros.github.io/?f49ef4d23d14e2c204648514729a7d850f62cf13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow and the world of web development. You're indeed getting a little ahead of yourself, but that's a great attitude.

To be able to *fetch* all the images from a folder automatically, you need a programming language. Javascript is one of those programming languages, but Javascript is *client side*.

Client side means that the code you've written is executed by the users' browser. This means that as long as the user has access to the folder with your images he/she is able to fetch all the images and display them on the webpage. Most servers, the computer your website is hosted on, take security measures to make sure that the user can't access a directory, only the contents. This means that the user cannot know how many images are in the directory.

Javascript is also very slow in doing this, as first the page needs to load; run the javascript; loop over every image in a directory; display them one by one; end the script.

So what you need is PHP, a serverside language. This will be run before the user gets the page, the server executes the code. This means that you have access to the folder containing the images and are able to loop over them, get the images and put them in HTML tags to send to the user with the page.

But PHP needs a lot more than just a .html file, it needs a .php file and your computer or server has to know about PHP and what to do with it.

If you want to learn more about PHP W3Schools has a great guide on the basics of PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/php/

But I recommend sticking with HTML and CSS right now and really try to understand how it works and why it does what it does.

Goodluck!